# Is there a way to plot a line graph with integer x values but label each point on the x axis with a string?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, charts, vb.net-2010

I'm producing a line graph and I'm plotting points according to x and y values using points.addxy(X, Y). However the xvalues are plotted through regular intervals which I want to have labeled below the axis. My code is below:

```
        Dim AllRaceArray() As String = GetAllRaceArray() 'Array of The race names in date order
    Dim RaceIDs() As Integer = GetAllRaceID() 'Array Of The Race IDs Paralell to the above array  
    Dim Xnum As Integer = AllRaceArray.Length
    Dim Interval As Integer = Math.Floor(Chart1.Size.Width / Xnum)
    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    For i = 0 To 3
        If CompareSlotEmpty(i) = False Then
            Chart1.Series.Add(i & CompPaddler(i).Name)
            Chart1.Series(i).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            Chart1.Series(i).XValueType = ChartValueType.String
            Chart1.Series(i).BorderWidth = 2
            Chart1.Series(i).MarkerStyle = DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Circle
            Chart1.Series(i).MarkerSize = 8
            For p = 0 To Xnum - 1
                For q = 0 To CompPaddler(i).RacePoints.Length - 1
                    If CompPaddler(i).RacePoints(q).RaceID = RaceIDs(p) Then
                        Chart1.Series(i).Points.AddXY(Interval * p, CompPaddler(i).RacePoints(q).Points) ' this point plot creates the correct ordering

                        Chart1.Series(i).Points.AddXY(AllRaceArray(p), CompPaddler(i).RacePoints(q).Points) ' this point plot creates the correct labels
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
        ' EDIT
        ' This below Section has now been added but nothing appears below the axis at all now
        For t = 0 To Chart1.Series(i).Points.Count - 1
            Chart1.Series(i).Points(t).AxisLabel = AllRaceArray(t)
        Next
        'EDIT
    Next
```

As annotated above One chart series creates the correct looking graph (http://tinypic.com/r/sobwbc/9) but x axis labels. Then the second plotter plots the correct labels but the ordering and scale gets messed up (http://tinypic.com/r/2w2g5s4/9).

TLDR: How to I change the xAxis Labels to strings that line up with regularly interval points?

Edit: I have added a loop to change the .axislabel but now nothing shows below the axis

Comment: Did you try searching ".net chart label" at all? Maybe read [some documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx)?

Comment: I did have a look at that before using it with the top point plot line, I will have another quick look though as I have changed some small sections since.

Comment: @AFriend      I have just tried adding this:                                                                                For t = 0 To Chart1.Series(i).Points.Count - 1
                Chart1.Series(i).Points(t).AxisLabel = AllRaceArray(t)
 Next                                                                                                                 But nothing Appears below the x axis at all